# Multiplying inventory with values

Tags: python-2.7

I was wondering whether there is an easier way of multiplying the inventory I have by their values assigned? I came out with the below code, which seems to work but it looks lengthy.

```
score = {
            "handle" : 4 ,
            "blade" : 3 ,
            "bottle" : 10 ,
            "full blade" : 10 
         }

inventory = ["handle", "blade", "bottle", "full blade"]

list = []

def ScoreCompute():
    for x in inventory:
        list.append(score.get(x))

ScoreCompute()
print sum(list)
x = sum(list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>>> sum(score.values())
```

Python dictionaries have lots of convenience methods/accessors, specifically for these types of things. First, if you want every item (key, value, key-value pair) in a dictionary, you probably don't need to use the `.get(...)` syntax.

If you want just the keys, you could do:

```
for key in score:
```

(Note: `for key in score.keys():` works as well, but in Python3, it's unnecessary, and in Python2, it can give a performance hit; `for key in score.iterkeys()` works without creating a temporary list, but there's probably no reason to call `score.iterkeys()` over just 'score`, at least not that I can think of off-hand.)

If you want just the values, Python provides a built-in, efficient method for though - no need to construct an entire new list of the values, just to `sum` them and then throw the list away. This gets into the topic of `generator`s, but that seems a bit of a digression here. Suffice to say,

```
for value in score.itervalues():
```

would let you look at and examine each of the values. You don't know which key goes with which value, but in your particular case, you don't care about the key, only the value, so that's fine.

If you want to look at both the key and the value at the same time, then all you need is

```
for key, value in score.iteritems():
```

Now, in your particular case, you just need each value once, and Python's `sum` is smart enough to figure out how to extract that from the `.values()` generator, so there's no need for an *explicit* for-loop. You can just write `sum(score.itervalues())` and get what you need.

It doesn't look like a particular concern here, but just to note: even though you don't have an explicit for-loop, it's still performing one "under the hood", so the longer the list, the longer it will take to `sum`. Again, though, this shouldn't matter for such a straight-forward and small example; it would be something to keep in mind if you were taking the sum of a list with millions and millions of values (or if you were calling `sum(score.itervalues())` over and over and over again).

Comment: Hi dwanderson, thanks for the reply. When I run the `for value in score.itervalues():` and print the `sum(score.itervalues())` there are four rows that appear. How do I restrict this to one row? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, those were two different aspects. If you just want the sum, only use `sum(score.itervalues())`; don't use the `for`-loop at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sum all the values in your dictionary `score`, you can do this with

```
sum(score.values())
```

or

```
sum(score.itervalues())
```

An additional note: In your example, `inventory` is equal to `score.keys()` (though, the order is not necessarily the same).

**Edit:**

As of Python 3.X `inventory` would equal something like `list(score.keys())`.

Thanks to @dwanderson for the hint.

Comment: `inventory` is only equal to `score.keys()` in Python2, not Python3, just to be precise. Edit: I now see the OP tagged this with Python2.7, so that was reasonable to not be explicit.

Comment: I included your hint nevertheless, because someone might not take a closer look at the tags.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit shorter if `inventory` has fewer entries than `score`:

```
>>> sum(score[key] for key in inventory)
27
```